# Revert a ViewController from a storyboard

Tags: xcode, git, uistoryboard

I have many view controllers in my story board. I don't want to revert my whole story board because I have added other view controllers and reverting a storyboard will lose all the view controllers that I haven't committed. Now how can I revert a single `viewController` from a `storyBoard`?

Comment: Based on my understanding storyboard gets saved as an XML. So please view before and after your commits (hopefully have a previously committed version) and discard irrelevant changes manually (could be tedious)

Answer (score 0):

Using git from command line, I don't know if it's possible. However, using a git app like [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), you can revert various chunck of code within the same file too. I have tested this myself and works perfectly.